# Concatenating string with itself two times give segmentation fault

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a[100] = "hi";

    strcat(a, a);
    strcat(a, a);

    printf("%s\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code Review is strictly for working code. I've migrated your question to our sister site where it is on-topic.

Answer (score 9):

From the definition of `strcat` in the C language standard, `§7.21.3.1/2`

`If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.`

My compiler crashes even when it's done once, as `strcat(a, a);` copies the first character of the second argument over the '\0' at the end of the first argument, then the second character of the second argument after it, etc until it encounters a '\0' in the second argument.. which never happens because that '\0' was gone when the first character was copied.

Answer (score 5):

From strcat(3) manpage:

> **`DESCRIPTION`**
>
> `The strcat() and strncat() functions append a copy of the null-terminated`
>   `string s2 to the end of the null-terminated string s1, then add a termi-`
>   `nating '\0'.  The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the`
>   `result.`
>
> `The strncat() function appends not more than n characters from s2, and`
>   `then adds a terminating`\0'.`
>
> **`The source and destination strings should not overlap, as the behavior is`
>
>   `undefined.`**

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior.

If you're in a loop, reading each `char` from a string, until `\0` is found, but at the same time you're appending (writing) chars to the end of it, when is the loop going to end?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the implementation is overwriting the null byte at the end:

```
Start: a = {h,i,\0}
         src^   vdst
next:  a = {h,i,h}
           src^   vdst
next:  a = {h,i,h,i}
             src^   vdst
next:  a = {h,i,h,i,h}
...
```

Because you overwrote the null terminator, your source string will never end and the method will keep copying until it tries to access memory it shouldn't and segfaults.