# I am trying to generate 1 GB of data by concatenating strings in C

Tags: c

Below is the code I have so far. It is giving segmentation fault after a couple of iterations. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *str; // 1GB = 1073741824  bytes
    char *temp;
    long long int i;
    str = (char *)malloc(1073741824);

    strcpy(str,"a");
    for(i = 1; i <= 73741824;i = i*2)
    {
        strcat(str,str);
    }
    free(str);
}
```

Comment: Same code as [recently asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48743609/4142924)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this one should be closed, since the "what happens if string is concatened to itself" question is already answered here: [Concatenating string with itself two times give segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231641/concatenating-string-with-itself-two-times-give-segmentation-fault).

However, since the close vote was rejected and there are number of other issues, I've fixed the code. This algorithm uses 2*SIZE memory, but it's significantly faster than the one in kamoroso94's answer (which uses less memory) and remains closer to the question author's idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE (1024 * 1024 * 1024) // convenient way how to define 1GB

int main()
{
    char *str;
    char *temp;
    long long int i;
    // don't forget to allocate space for the terminating character!
    str = malloc(SIZE + 1); // no need to typecast the result malloc()
    temp = malloc(SIZE + 1);
    // don't forget to check for allocation failures
    if (str == NULL || temp == NULL) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    strcpy(temp, "a");
    for(i = 1; i <= SIZE; i *= 2) {
        // concatenate the buffer to the string
        strcat(str, temp);
        // copy the whole string to the temporary buffer
        strcpy(temp, str);
    }
    printf("length of s = %u\n", strlen(str));
    free(str);
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: @kfx Thanks! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `strcat()` with the same string as both arguments, which is an error. See [the manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat):

> The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing some undefined behavior!  If you read the description of `strcat`, it mentions: "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined," ([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcat.html)).

If you think about it, it first copies the first byte of `str` to the null byte of `str`, and continues until the null byte.  Do you see the problem?  You overwrite it, so you will keep copying bytes until you encounter a garbage null byte.

The way around this is to not have the same source and destination string.  Also, why are you iterating until 73741824?  If you want a 1GB string, you should iterate until 1073741824.  Also keep in mind building the string this way is no more efficient than just concatenating "a" onto your string ~1 billion times.  Knowing that, that's what we'll end up doing to solve our problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char *str; // 1GB = 1073741824 bytes
  char *temp;
  long long int i;
  const size_t GB = 1073741824;

  str = (char *)malloc(GB);
  strcpy(str, "a");

  for(i = 1; i < GB; i++) {
    strcat(str + i, "a");
  }

  free(str);
}
```

**Edit:** if you prefer the original algorithm, I've fixed that as well.  Just make the corresponding changes.  This will avoid copying to any overlapping memory, and therefore, avoid any undefined behavior.

```
for(i = 1; i < GB; i *= 2) {
  str[i - 1] = '\0';
  strcat(str + i, str);
  str[i - 1] = 'a';
  str[2 * i - 1] = 'a';
  str[2 * i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Actually the OP's indended algorithm *is* more efficient than yours. This one has O(n^2) complexity, and for no good reason. This approach is also known as *Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*.

Comment: The number 73741824 was a typo. I actually meant 1073741824 only. How come the first byte being copied to `str` is null. To avoid it, I am first coping  ` "a" ` to `str` . Also, the way you are iterating the loop ~billion times, I also did it but it is taking an enormous amount of time. By my way, it would take 30 iterations but I can see it now that my way gives an unidentified behaviour.

Comment: See [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm).

Comment: That's better, but you still don't allocate enough memory.

Comment: @kfx if you're talking about the `<=` I'm working on an edit, but now I see my OBO!